# R - Dynamic conditions in function

Tags: r

I wrote a function that calculates the difference of some value between two years under certain conditions. The factor levels have to match exactly in order to substract the values.

Dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(year=rep(2001:2003,each=4),
                 country=rep(c("A","B"),6),
                 categorie=rep(letters[3:6],3),
                 animal=rep(LETTERS[7:10],3),
                 value=sample(1:10,12,replace=T))

df
year country categorie animal value
1  2001       A         c      G     9
2  2001       B         d      H     2
3  2001       A         e      I     8
4  2001       B         f      J     7
5  2002       A         c      G     4
6  2002       B         d      H     3
7  2002       A         e      I     4
8  2002       B         f      J     4
9  2003       A         c      G    10
10 2003       B         d      H     1
11 2003       A         e      I     4
12 2003       B         f      J    10
```

The value in row 5 should be substracted from the value in row 1 because it is the subsequent year and has the same attributes (categorie=A, categorie=c, animal=G).

The function below works fine.

```
calc.change <- function(df, cols){
  for(i in cols){
    p <- vector(mode="numeric", length = nrow(df))
    for(k in seq_len(nrow(df))){
      #first year is NA because no difference can be calculated
      if(df$year[k]==min(df$year[df$country==df$country[k] & 
         df$categorie==df$categorie[k] & df$animal==df$animal[k]])){
        p[k] <- NA
      } else {
        p[k] <- df[[i]][k]-df[[i]][df$year==df$year[k]-1 & df$categorie==df$categorie[k]
                                 & df$animal==df$animal[k] & df$country==df$country[k]]
      }
    }
    df <- cbind(df, p)
    names(df)[names(df)=="p"] <- paste0(i,".change")
  }
  return(df)
}

foo <- calc.change(df, "value")


foo
year country categorie animal value value.change
1  2001       A         c      G     4           NA
2  2001       B         d      H     4           NA
3  2001       A         e      I     9           NA
4  2001       B         f      J     1           NA
5  2002       A         c      G     2           -2
6  2002       B         d      H     3           -1
7  2002       A         e      I     2           -7
8  2002       B         f      J     5            4
9  2003       A         c      G     4            2
10 2003       B         d      H    10            7
11 2003       A         e      I    10            8
12 2003       B         f      J     5            0
```

However, the function does not work anymore if one of the columns `country categorie` or `animal` is missing.

```
foobar <- aggregate(value ~ year+country, df, mean)

head(foobar)
    year country value
1 2001       A   6.5
2 2002       A   2.0
3 2003       A   7.0
4 2001       B   2.5
5 2002       B   4.0
6 2003       B   7.5

calc.change(foobar, value) #gives an error
```

That is clear because they are required by several if-statements and `&` operators.
Is it possible not to hardcode the column names, but to only pass exsting ones?
I would like to make it as flexible as possible.

Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add your desired output based on the input?

Answer (score -1):

You could use higher order functions in R. That is you can pass a function to a function

```
test <- function(df,k)
   df$year[k]==min(df$year[df$country==df$country[k] & 
           df$categorie==df$categorie[k] & df$animal==df$animal[k]])



calc.change <- function(df, cols,test){
  for(i in cols){
    p <- vector(mode="numeric", length = nrow(df))
    for(k in seq_len(nrow(df))){
      #first year is NA because no difference can be calculated
      if(test(df,k){
        p[k] <- NA
      } else {
        p[k] <- df[[i]][k]-df[[i]][df$year==df$year[k]-1 & df$categorie==df$categorie[k]
                                 & df$animal==df$animal[k] & df$country==df$country[k]]
      }
    }
    df <- cbind(df, p)
    names(df)[names(df)=="p"] <- paste0(i,".change")
  }
  return(df)
}

calc.change(df, "value",test)
```

You can now replace `test` by any function that taka a dataframe and a integear and return a boolean.